# How can i share a "text" on facebook from my cordova based app?

Tags: cordova, facebook-graph-api

Note: This is not a duplicate. The previous questions are outdated and doesnt really solve the problem, also facebook policy had changed.

from [facebook devs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share), here's what ive got so far:

```
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : 'myid',
              xfbml      : true,
              version    : 'v2.1'
            })
          }

          (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=479867658820979&version=v2.0";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))
         </script>
```

im stuck here, dont really know what im doing. also ive tried different kinds of plugins from cordova but i think this is the most legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to share a text then you can use this library

[OpenFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB)

```
openFB.api({path: '/me/friends', success: successHandler, error: errorHandler});

openFB.api(
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/me/feed',
    params: {
        message: 'Testing the Facebook Graph API'
    },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

OR you can use this plugin too

[Social Sharing](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

Comment: thank you! ill try this one sir. also ive used the plugin. the problem is facebook doesnt allow pre defined messages